# F# in Monodevelop: Stack traces when opening .fsx file

Tags: ubuntu, f#, monodevelop

Extension .fsx stands for an Fsharp File that will be compiled to an executable.

Cannot open .fsx files in Monodevelop (from Ubuntu maverick repo).
TargetInvocationException , FileNameNotResolved

[Please see screenshot on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/30487090@N02/5356880304/)

When I rename the file to .fs (Fsharp script file) then it can be opened.

Actually, I have three questions:

1. Why am I getting this stack trace? I just imported/added the file and it is indeed in the solution folder.
2. How to fix monodevelop?
3. How can I
   get the text of the stack trace into
   a log file?

Comment: To be clear, .fsx is for scripts, and .fs is for compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error used to happen with older versions of F#. Are you using [November 2010 F# update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/11/10/november-2010-f-2-0-free-tools-update.aspx)?

(To give some more details - There is nothing wrong with the `fsx` file, but the language service fails when loading. The problem is that the F# IntelliSense service running in MonoDevelop cannot locate some referenced assembly. This is done by calling the F# compiler and F# compiler contained error (in IntelliSense code when on Mono) where it tries to load wrong file e.g. `System` instead of `System.dll` - the November 2010 update should fix this).

If updating F# doesn't resolve the problem, can you send a repro to the F# open source mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/fsharp-opensource?

Comment: I was using fsharp_2.0-1_all.deb from 2010-11-06 downloaded from codeplex.com

http://download.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=fsxplat&DownloadId=166083&FileTime=129338912182530000&Build=17275

Thanks Thomas, for the great work you are doing on all things F#! (I am just beginning with the language, but I've followed your screencasts for instance)

Comment: in early nov. 2010 there were TWO files fsharp_2.0-1_all.deb with the SAME FILENAME available for download on the official website(s). 
Note the date differences and the size differences:

3917318 2010-11-06 14:10 fsharp_2.0-1_all.deb

5060774 2010-11-12 19:24 fsharp_2.0-1_all(2).deb
   I removed the fsharp.deb package using synaptic. Then
after updating mono (as recom. in answer by Kevin Cantu) the fsharp dlls were installed into a new GAC in /usr/local/lib/mono/gac. Problem solved by updating fsharp and mono.

Comment: I've heard that the Mono folks are serious about wanting to package F# with their stuff, so this should all get easier soon.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your Mono.  Ubuntu 10.10 has an old version of Mono that seems to cause a lot of problems with `fsi.exe`.  And it is *sloooow*.  Considering F#, at least, Debian (upstream) and Ubuntu need to upgrade 2.6.7 to one of the 2.8.x releases soon!

I've been playing around with [this version](ftp://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/sources/mono/mono-2.8.2.tar.bz2) of Mono 2.8.2 and my programs are behaving **much** better.  (I haven't synced up the `cli` executable and MonoDevelop yet, but just running `/new/path/mono fsc.exe` or whatever, so far, but I'm a lot happier.)

Comment: I have downloaded the mono 2.8.2 which you recommended. Built it from source, installed to /usr/local, set env var MONO_GAC_PREFIX=/usr/local:/usr in /etc/profile.d/myshellscript.sh and rebooted. 
Monodevelop now says it prefers 2.8.2 as default, 2.6.7 as fallback.
Problem with fsx files remains. I'll keep trying.